# Reloading table view without user interactions while app is foreground

Tags: uitableview, swift3, reloaddata

Swift provides a powerful way to update table view changes when you're using `reloadData()`. But it's works on the certain places as such `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` or `refreshControl`. It would be better when the `tableView` gets an automatic way to reload data. It's possible to update the `tableView` when the app is foreground? You can see such as effect in the iOS Reminders app.

Example: iOS Reminder

Let's say you've scheduled reminder. And you're still using the app, at this time your scheduled notification is fired and prompted about you must be do something. At this time your scheduled reminder becomes an overdue item, when you're doing nothing and the `detailTextLabel` gets a red color. There is no any user interactions.

Here's what I've done:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    let managedObject = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = managedObject.value(forKey: "string") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(managedObject.value(forKey: "date") as! Date)"

    print("Get called")

    for viewController in (self.tabBarController?.viewControllers)! {

        let overdue = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter({ (record) -> Bool in
            return (record.date?.compare(Date()) != .orderedDescending)
        })

        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1 {

            if overdue?.count == 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = ""
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeColor = UIColor.clear

                })
            } else if overdue?.count != 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "\(overdue!.count)"
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

                })
            }
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        if managedObject.date?.compare(Date()) != .orderedDescending {
         cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
         cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Call `reloadData()` from where you receive the notification.

Comment: Did you mean local or remote notification?

Comment: That does not matter. How I understand, you want to reloadData() when whatever notification is triggered.

Comment: The UserNotificationCenterDelegate methods requires user interactions or not?

Comment: @shallowThought Yeah! Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Maybe update your question with a more detailed description of your use case.